# Python's glob module and unix' find command don't recognize non-ascii

Tags: python, unix, encoding

I am on Mac OS X 10.8.2

When I try to find files with filenames that contain non-ASCII-characters I get no results although I know for sure that they are existing. Take for example the console input

```
> find */Bärlauch*
```

I get no results. But if I try without the umlaut I get

```
> find */B*rlauch*
images/Bärlauch1.JPG
```

So the file is definitely existing. If I rename the file replacing 'ä' by 'ae' the file is being found.

Similarily the Python module `glob` is not able to find the file:

```
>>> glob.glob('*/B*rlauch*')
['images/Bärlauch1.JPG']
>>> glob.glob('*/Bärlauch*')
[]
```

I figured out it must have something to do with the encoding but my terminal is set to be utf-8 and I am using Python 3.3.0 which uses unicode strings.

Comment: Mac uses decomposed unicode characters by default. Try matching on `'*/Ba\xcc\x88rlauch*'`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I just tried your suggestion both with `find`and with `glob`. No result... But thanks for helping

Comment: What does `[repr(e) for e in os.listdir()]` on that directory give you? The exact python representation please.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think we're thinking along the same lines... I recall issues with `glob` and `fnmatch` back in the 2.x series (different bits were over-ruling unicode back to something else), but AFAIK they were resolved by 2.6-ish). I would also be tempted to just use `glob('*')` and then `fnmatch.filter` to see what happens...

Comment: `["'.DS_Store'", "'images3 1440x960'", "'Baum.csv'", "'Baum.xlsx'", "'BaumUTF-8.csv'", "'images 012013'", "'images'", "'convImg.py'", "'DB.csv'", "'images2 1440x960'"]` is the exact python representation returned by python shell.

Comment: I get `['.DS_Store', 'Akelei1.JPG', 'Akelei2.JPG', 'Bärlauch1.JPG', 'Enzian1.jpg', 'Huflattich1.JPG', 'Pestwurz1.jpg', 'Pestwurz2.JPG', 'Seidelbast1.JPG', 'Silberdistel1.jpg', 'Traubenkirsche St.JPG', 'Traubenkirsche1.JPG', 'Traubenkirsche2.JPG', 'Wildkirsche2.JPG', 'Wolliger Schneeball1.JPG']`. Bärlauch is displayed correctly in the terminal.

Comment: @JonClements I also tried using `fnmatch.filter` but it did not work... Is it possible this is a bug in glob or fnmatch?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mac OS X uses denormalized characters *always* for filenames on HFS+. Use `unicodedata.normalize('NFD', pattern)` to denormalize the glob pattern.

```
import unicodedata

glob.glob(unicodedata.normalize('NFD', '*/Bärlauch*'))
```

Comment: @Martijn I'm not sure about you, but I'm thinking something like this should probably go on Python's bug tracker...

Comment: Also see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10476/how-to-enter-special-characters-so-that-bash-terminal-understands-them for your same problem. This is not a Python bug.

Comment: @mmgp okay - but no reason Python shouldn't be able this without resorting to the above code... (there's already enough in the stdlib that deals with different platforms/systems - that I wouldn't see this massively different to those)

Comment: This will likely introduce a lot of issues, since you need extra care when comparing normalized and non-normalized text. Actually, even between normalized text, but with different normalization causes trouble of course.

Comment: I think it is certainly a bug if it wouldn't work on a non HFS+ disk. I am not sure about that and currently have no ability to test but maybe someone could test it...

Comment: @JonClements: It depends entirely on the filesystem; a mounted SMB share does not necessarily use the same denormalized characters.

Comment: Linux uses the former method, called Normal-Form-Composed (or NFC), and Mac OS X uses the latter method, called Normal-Form-Decomposed (NFD).
So if you want to make your code work on Linux and OS X, you need to normalise accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Python programs are fundamentally text files. Conventionally, people write them using only characters from the ASCII character set, and thus do not have to think about the encoding they write them in: all character sets agree on how ASCII characters should be decoded.

You have written a Python program using a non-ASCII character. Your program thus comes with an implicit encoding (which you haven't mentioned): to save such a file, you have to decide how you are going to represent a-umlaut on disk. I would guess that perhaps your editor has chosen something non-Unicode for you.

Anyway, there are two ways around such a problem: either you can restrict yourself to using only ASCII characters in the source code of your program, or you can declare to Python that you want it to read the text file with a specific encoding.

To do the former, you should replace the a-umlaut with its Unicode escape sequence (which I think is `\x0228` but can't test at the moment). To do the latter, you should add a coding declaration at the top of the file:

```
# -*- coding: <your encoding> -*-
```

Comment: Setting source encoding of UTF8 is irrelevant for Python 3, since that is already assumed.

Comment: for further reading: [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#encodings-pep-263) and [PEP 263](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)

Comment: Yes you are probably right programs should only be written in ASCII. To clarify, I ran the python commands in the python shell and also tried writing a source file with the encoding added as you suggested. Neither did work. I also tried by escaping `\u00E4` which also didn't work. But thanks for your suggestions! –